# What stream do files use?

Tags: c++, stream

When reading data through `cin`, the `stdin` stream is used. How about files? Do they use a particular stream object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a complete hierarchy of stream classes, you can see the doccumentation **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/)**.

Most notable amongst them are **[ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/)** and **[ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/)** for reading and writing to files respectively.

Answer (score 2):

They use what you choose :)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


std::ifstream input("test.txt");

int i;
if (input >> i)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;


std::string s;
if (std::getline(input, s))
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

You could replace the name `input` by a name of your own chosing: it's just an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) and [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) for reading and writing files. You have to include fstream.